# Typographie : utilisation du point virgule pour une liste

Tags: typographie, ponctuation

Je voudrais énumérer, par exemple dans un C.V., une liste de compétences.
Qu'est-ce qui est le plus juste entre :

> Langues : Français ; Persan ; Anglais ; Espagnol

et :

> Langues : Français, Persan, Anglais, Espagnol

Comment: Ce que j'en sais : Pas de majuscule après un point virgule, que je me plais à utiliser pour marquer une pause équivalente à un point, sans pour autant terminer la phrase. ex: Avant d'être fort comme un chêne; il faut être fort comme un gland(une des citations que je préfère).

Comment: De toute façon, le point virgule est surtout utilisé pour faire des clins d'œil… ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On a

> Par exemple, dans une énumération, la virgule sépare les termes énumérés, sauf, en français, pour le dernier, qui n'est pas précédé d'une virgule quand il est précédé par une conjonction (par exemple « et »)
>   ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgule#Linguistique_et_typographie))

et

> Dans une énumération, les différents éléments sont séparés par une virgule, sauf les deux derniers où *et* prend d’ordinaire la place de la virgule.
>   ([banque de dépannage linguistique](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3446))

D'un autre côté

> On peut employer le point-virgule pour séparer les éléments d'une énumération horizontale, et ce, peu importe la longueur des éléments. Le point-virgule est particulièrement utile lorsque certains éléments de l'énumération comportent une ou plusieurs virgules; il permet alors d'éviter la confusion que créerait une virgule, puisqu'on ne saurait plus très bien comment séparer les éléments. Le point-virgule peut aussi être employé pour séparer les éléments d'une énumération ne comportant aucun autre signe de ponctuation.
>   ([banque de dépannage linguistique](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3346))

Donc les deux sont acceptés, c'est toi qui choisis ce que tu trouves le plus joli et le plus logique. En ce qui me concerne je n'utilise les point-virgules que quand les énumérés contiennent des virgules.

Answer (score 8):

J'utiliserais ici des virgules sans hésiter (en mettant *langues* au pluriel, sans majuscules aux noms de langues et en utilisant un *et* avant la dernière).

Des points virgules me semblent convenir si on énumère des propositions ou des unités syntaxiques d'une complexité comparable.

Une exception : si la mise en forme se fait sous forme de listes, comme ceci

> Langues :
>
> - français ;
> - persan ;
> - anglais ;
> - espagnol.

j'utiliserais le même signe pour toutes les listes du documents (j'ai mis ici un point virgule, le plus vraisemblable dans un document complexe ; dans un CV, une virgule ou même aucun signe peut convenir).