# Point d'exclamation à la fin d'une liste

Tags: ponctuation, exclamations

Devrais-je mettre le point d'exclamation à la fin d'un item d'une liste ou mettre la ponctuation de la liste ?

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur FrenchSE ! Vous devriez donner plus de contexte et donner un exemple pour nous aider à comprendre votre question. Pensez à faire un [tour] pour trouver l'inspiration ! [Ceci](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/typographie-utilisation-du-point-virgule-pour-une-liste) pourrait vous aider.

Answer (score 6):

Il est possible de mettre des points d'exclamation à certains membres d'une énumération.

Je n'ai pas trouvé de références précises sur le sujet mais à priori, si l'énumération est présentée en ligne, les séparateurs (virgules ou plus rarement point-virgules) sont optionnels, le point d'exclamation ayant valeur de « [virgule expressive](http://editions-internetparc-files.pbworks.com/f/La+Ponctuation+par+Jean-Pierre+Leclercq.pdf) » :

> Dans son sac, il y avait des clés, un porte-monnaie, un couteau ! une paire de lunettes, des faux papiers ! et un parapluie.

ou

> Dans son sac, il y avait des clés, un porte-monnaie, un couteau !, une paire de lunettes, des faux papiers ! et un parapluie.

Dans ce dernier cas, la règle « pas d'espace avant une virgule » prends le pas sur « une espace avant et après un point d'exclamation ».

De même, si l'énumération est présentée en colonnes, le point d'exclamation peut  remplacer le point-virgule :

> Dans son sac, il y avait :
>   — ses clés ;
>   — un porte-monnaie ;
>   — un couteau !
>   — une paire de lunettes ;
>   — des faux papiers !
>   — un parapluie.

ou pas :

> …
>   — un couteau ! ;
>   …

Answer (score -1):

Dans l'absolu si tu as une raison particulière je ne vois pas de raison de l'interdire (ça reste informel)

Mais en règle générale il n'y a pas besoin de ponctuation dans une liste.

Sans plus de contexte, difficile de répondre à ta question.

Comment: ?? La ponctuation s'impose toujours dans une liste, soit une virgule, soit un point-virgule.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui pardon, je parlais de ponctuation forte comme les points d'exclamation dont parlait OP

Comment: Un point d'exclamation n'est une ponctuation forte que lorsqu'il termine une phrase. On doit le considérer comme une ponctuation faible quand il ne l'interrompt pas et n'est donc pas suivi d'une majuscule.

Comment: Façon de parler. Et je ne vois pas dans quel cas un point d'exclamation en milieu de phrase est correct.

Comment: « Ah ! non ! c'est un peu court, jeune homme ! » ;-)

Comment: Maintenant j'écrirais "Ah, non ! C'est un peu court, jeune homme !". J'ai déjà lu ce genre d'orthographe mais ça fait très vieilli je trouve ^^

Comment: Il s'agit ici d'une seule phrase. On ne peut pas la couper en deux sous prétexte de ne pas apprécier sa ponctuation. Académie Française: [*Les points de suspension, de même que le point d’interrogation et le point d’exclamation, peuvent clore une phrase comme le fait le point. Ils sont alors suivis d’une majuscule marquant le début d’une phrase complète. Mais ils sont évidemment suivis d’une minuscule quand c’est la même phrase qui continue*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/alexandra-r-france)

Comment: Au temps pour moi. Je trouve toujours que ça fait vieillot, et c'est pas exactement l'académie française qui va changer ça, au contraire ;)